# Запуск разрешения Android по клику - Unity

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Необходимо вызвать разрешение использования микрофона при нажатии на кнопку, при старте не должно требовать разрешения, видел где-то видео об этом, не могу найти, помогите разобраться.

Comment: Это рантайм-пермишны, введены с Android 6 (Marshmallow). При нажатии на кнопку можно их просто требовать. И покажется окно. Но вообще, я считаю эти пермишны новые тааак дико загрязняют код. Использовать библиотеку Dexter удобнее

Comment: Можете подсказать, а как пользоваться Dexter? плагина не нашел